# SQL to select records for a specific date given created time and modified time

Tags: sql, t-sql

### CONTEXT

I've been asked by my management to "analyze" our issue tracking database - they use it to catalog our internal bugs, etc. My SQL and DB skills are **primitive** so I need some help.

### THE DATA

I received a single table of 3 million records. It accounts for 250K bugs. Each revision of a bug is a row in the table. That's how 250K bugs ends up in 3 million records.

The data looks like this

```
BugID  Created      Modified     AssignedTo  Priority  Status
27     mar-31-2003  mar-31-2003  mel         2         Open
27     mar-31-2003  apr-01-2003  mel         1         Open
27     mar-31-2003  apr-10-2003  steve       1         Fixed
```

Thus,  I have the complete history of every bug and can see how they have evolved every day.

### WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH

I have a lot of things I've been asked to provide as reports. But the most basic question I have been asked to do is enable someone to look at the bugs as they existed at a specific date.

For example, if someone asked for all the bugs on mar 1 2003, then bug 27 isn't in the result because it doesn't exist on that day. Or if they asked for the bugs on April 7 they'd see bug 27 and that still marked as open

### MY SPECIFIC QUESTION

Given the schema I outlined, what SQL query will provide a view of the records on a specific date?

### TECHNICAL DETAILS

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

### WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR

As I said my SQL skills are primitive. I was able use WHERE clauses to filter out modifications made after the target date and bugs that didn't exist by the target date, but wasn't able to find the single record happened on that date.

Comment: Who down-voted?  Please be a *help* by posting a comment as to why, so that the OP may address it?

Comment: As Dems pointed out, please let me know - I will spend the time to improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BugID ORDER BY Modified DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
  WHERE
    Modified <= @datetime_stamp
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

This assumes you want to see the fixed bugs.  If you want to filter out bugs that were fixed 'a long time ago' (say, 30 days), add this...

```
AND (Status <> 'Fixed' OR Modified >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, @datetime_stamp))
```