# SQL to add ValidUntil given a Modified Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

### CONTEXT

This is related to a previous question I asked recently: [SQL to select records for a specific date given created time and modified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555490/sql-to-select-records-for-a-specific-date-given-created-time-and-modified-time).

Please read it if you want further context on the question. A quick summary is that I have a table that contains the issue tracking data. It stores *each revision* made to issues. Each row is a revision and there is a column called "Modified" that indicates when the revision is active. In response to that question, someone (thank you) provided a query that enabled me to see the state of an issue on a specific day.

One suggestion I received in private was to simplify the query by adding a new column that stored the time that the revision is no longer valid.

In other words, to take a Modified field and Compute the value for "ValidUntil"

### THE INPUT DATA

looks like this

```
BugID  Created      Modified     Status
27     mar-31-2003  mar-31-2003  Open
27     mar-31-2003  apr-01-2003  Open
27     mar-31-2003  apr-10-2003  Fixed
```

### THE DESIRED OUPUT DATA

looks like this

```
BugID  Created      Modified     ValidUntil  Status
27     mar-31-2003  mar-31-2003  apr-01-2003  Open
27     mar-31-2003  apr-01-2003  apr-10-2003  Open
27     mar-31-2003  apr-10-2003  NULL         Fixed
```

### MY SPECIFIC QUESTION

I can create the ValidUntil column in database.

Ideally, I'm looking for the SQL that can insert the correct ValidUtil dates.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR

Frankly, nothing. This is so far beyond my expertise I have no clue what to do.

### TECHNICAL NOTES

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Check this query:

```
UPDATE yourtable toUpd
   SET toUpd.ValidUntil = fromUpd.Modified
  FROM yourtable fromUpd
 WHERE fromUpd.BugId = toUpd.BugId
   and fromUpd.modfified > toUpd.Modified
   and not exists
         (SELECT 1
            FROM yourtable innerTable
           WHERE fromUpd.BudId = innerTable.BugId
             and fromUpd.Modified > innerTable.Modified
             and toUpd.Modified < innerTable.Modified
         )
```

Maybe it has some mistake but you can get the idea :-)